# How to add a new .cpp file to, and then build, a c++ library for Android?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, building

I'm making a Unity3d plugin for [this](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/) c++ library for Android. Ive gotten it to work in windows by opening the visual studio project the library makers provided, adding a new .cpp file to it with my API code and building to a dll.
I'm wondering now how I can add this new .cpp file to the library and build it for Android.
So far I have installed the Android sdk and ndk on a machine with ubuntu and successfully built the original library using ndk-build (as per [these](http://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_android.html) instructions)
I'm guessing it is not as simple as copying my .cpp file into the folder and building as there are AndroidManifest.xml files and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AndroidManifest.xml file is not pertinent for an NDK build.

You will need to find the appropriate Android.mk file. You may need to add the file name into the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` in that make file, although they may have it set up to compile all the .cpp files in the directory or something more intelligent along those lines. It is, after all, a regular make file.

See [here](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html) for info on the Android.mk file specifics.

Edit:

I suppose I should add that it would be the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` preceding the relevant `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` for the library you intend to build. Each make file may contain an arbitrary number of targets, although in the simplest case it's usually one make file to build a library.